# Volito2 replacement pen

Tags: replace, pen, wacom

I bought a Wacom volito2(ctf-420)drawing tablet second-hand the other day, but it did’nt come with the pen. I was just wondering if anyone knows a place where i could get a replacement pen.

Thanks in advance :P